# setState not updating asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is a functional react component using react hooks - state is updating in a strange way breaking my component flow. Any thoughts on how why this is happening and how to reliably update the state that's required by subcomponents. At the moment, my firestore save doesn't work as it needs the user id and it's not getting it from the state as it's lagging in updating...

```
const XYZ = (props) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    ...props,
  });

  const getinitdata = async () => {
    let user = await utils.getUser();
    console.log("1", user.uid); //USERID
    await setData({ ...data, uid: user.uid });
    console.log("3", data.uid); //UNDEFINED
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    getinitdata();
    console.log("2", data.uid); //UNDEFINED
    return () => {
      console.log("componentWillUnmount");
    };
  }, []); // empty-array means don't watch for any updates

  console.log("4", data.uid); //USERID

  return (

    <div>{data.uid}</div>


  );
}
```

the console.log's from above are printing as follows:

```
componentDidMount
2 undefined
1 KMDTFXxktUTwq6Kg34l8r5qWkAL
4 KMDTFXxktUTwq6Kg34l8r5qWkAL
3 undefined
```

The goal is simply to make sure the setData is updating the state by adding some data, like uid here. So using state as a temporary store.

This data should then be available in case a function needs to write it to a db as part of a transaction like a booking, for example.

What I found as quite different from class-based this.setState({smth:smth}), which I can rely on to update the state immediately, the functional one can't be relied on for that - for example, this doesn't update the state setData({...data, smth:smth}) for the data.smth to be non-null and ready to be sent.

This takes away from the this.setState capabilities and not sure what workaround to use to get the state to store a var right after it's available, uid, etc...

Any thoughts on how to do that would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> The question remains why console.log("3", data.uid); is undefined despite await before the setData.

Your arrow function in `useEffect` **captures** the `data` variable, and calling `setData` does not update the value of `data` in that function, whether or not you use `await`. How could it? `data` is declared `const`, so anything that sees it gets the initial value. The point of calling `setData` is to get a new value of `data` on the next rerender.

If you want a value you can change in `useEffect` and read immediately after, use `const data = useRef` and change the `data.current` field to the value you want.

P.S., you usually [shouldn't copy props to state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state).

**EDIT:** Provided example

```
const XYZ = props => {
  const data = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fn = async () => {
      data.current = 1;
      await delay(1000);
      data.current = 2;
      console.log(data.current); // 2
    };
    fn();
  }, []);
  return /* whatever */
};
```

Comment: "If you want a value you can change in useEffect and read immediately after, use const data = useRef and change the data.current field to the value you want."

Can you please show an example of a value being added to the state onmount and becoming immediately available to subcomponents, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is useref better than usestate for this? I need the data to be part of state to be used by sub-components when rendering. In particular, I need to make a window.location.search parsing which seems to be possible only after a componentmount. I wonder what is the best way to setState to capture it before the first render?

Comment: "The point of calling setData is to get a new value of data on the next rerender." 
Not sure if I'm following you. Did you see the console.logs above?
data.uid is printing userid under 4 before a render and _before_ it prints undefined again under 3...

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues with the code:

- `setData` does not return a promise. Actually it does not return anything. So use `await` on it has no effect.
- In the effect function, you are calling `getInitialData` which is a async function but you are not waiting for its completion.

Assumming that you want to fetch the user id on mount and then execute something once the user id is available, you can some thing like:

```
const getInitialData = async () => {
    let user = await utils.getUser();
    setData({ ...data, uid: user.uid });
}

useEffect(() => {
    getInitialData();   
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if(data.uid) {
         // whatever needs to be done once uid is available.
    }
}, [data.uid]);
```

Comment: Thanks, what I simply need is to make sure the setData is updating the state by adding some data, like uid here. This data should then be available in case a function needs to write it to a db as part of a transaction like a booking, for example. 

What I found as quite different from class-based this.setState({smth:smth}), which I can rely on to update the state immediately, the functional one is not so reliable - for example, this doesn't update the state setData({...data, smth:smth}) for the data.smth to be non-null and ready to be sent, etc which seems a flaw and workaround needed